# Hide and show form by clicking the button with the ID button in Angularjs

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have an `a` tag as follows:

```html
<a id="@item.PollMatchId" value="@item.PollMatchId" data-ng-click="showform($event)" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs editresult">edit</a>
```

I want to display this `form` tag when ID click on this tag

```html
<form ng-hide="IsVisible" asp-controller="Matches" data-ajax-method asp-route-id="@item.PollMatchId" data-ajax="true">
```

Angular Function:

```js
$scope.showform = function (event) {
  var idmatch = event.target.id;
  $scope.IsVisible = $scope.IsVisible(idmatch) = true;
}
```

How to give an event to IsVisible to be displayed based on the same event ID form?